# Responsive Div Heights that Stretch the Width of the Browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to setup a responsive div height - I think I'm almost there but there's some distortion happening when I resize my browser. Here is a fiddle file so you can take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/td5n8ky9/10/

The problem is in the bottom 2 divs - I need a grey bar the width of the screen to hold the 3 'box.jpeg' files and the rest of the page underneath to be white. If you resize the browser, you'll see the grey bar's height becomes too small. I'm hoping to solve this problem without using Jquery (although I will if I must) and without adding additional media queries, since I would like the transitions upon resizing the browser to be relatively smooth. Thanks for your time.

SOURCE CODE

```
<div class="container">

        <nav>
            <ul id="mobile_active">
                <li class="link"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="link"><a href="#">Creative</a></li>

                <li id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="links/Logo.png"/></a></li>

                <li class="link"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="link"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <header><a class="mobile_menu"></a></header>

</div>

<div class="line"></div>

<div class="container">              
    <div id="G">
       <img src="links/06-Grafiks-G.png"/>

    <div id="Text-Scroller">
       <h1>headline</h1>
       <p>Body Text</p>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>

<div id="Gray"></div>

<div class="container">
    <article class="newsfeed"><img src="links/box1.jpg"/></article>
    <article class="newsfeed"><img src="links/box2.jpg"/></article>
    <article class="newsfeed"><img src="links/box3.jpg"/></article>
</div>

<div class="container">
        <div class="contact"><p>Address<br>Location</p></div>
        <div class="contact"><p>Phone • Fax<br>Email</p></div>
        <div class="contact"><p>Hours<br>Closed</p></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {max-width: 950px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;}

.line {clear:both; border-bottom: medium solid #bbb1a6; overflow:visible;}

.contact{width:27.75%; padding-left:2.75%; background-color:#FFF; height: 73%; padding-right:2.75%; float:left;}
.contact p {font-size:0.85em; text-align:center;}

#G{position:relative; clear:both; margin:0; height:auto; padding:0; line-height:0;}
#G img {width:95%; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:2.5%; padding-right:2.5%;}

#Text-Scroller{width:66%; padding-top:33%;margin:0 auto; z-index:2; top:0; right:0; left:0; 
text-align:center; position:absolute; line-height:1.35em;}

h1{font-size:1.45em; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;color:#A54499;}
p{font-size:1em}

nav ul {list-style: none; padding: 0; text-align: center;}
nav li {display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom;}

nav li a {
  color: #949c50;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
  margin: 0;}

nav li a:hover {color:#a54499;}
a.mobile_menu {display:none;}

li#logo {top:0; left:50%; margin-top:-16px;}

#Gray{width:100%; height:27%; background-color:#bbb1a6; position:absolute;}

.newsfeed img{width:30%; padding: 1.5%; float:right; height:auto;}


@media (max-width: 950px) {

.container {width: 100%;}

#Text-Scroller{line-height:1em;}

.line {clear:both; border-bottom: medium solid #bbb1a6; overflow:visible; margin-top: 125px;}

h1{font-size:1.1em; font-weight:bold; color:#A54499;}
p{font-size:0.85em}

nav {position: relative; top: 113px;}
nav ul {padding-top:50px;}

li#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {h1{font-size:0.9em;} p{font-size:0.75em}}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
.container {width: 100%; height:auto;}
.line {display:none;}
.newsfeed img{width:100%; padding-left:0; padding-right:0;}
.contact{width:100%; padding:0;}

h1{font-size:1.45em; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;color:#A54499;}
p{font-size:1em}

header {height:35px;top:185px; display:block;}
#Gray{display:none;}
#Text-Scroller{width:95%; padding-top:2.5%;margin:0 auto; z-index:0; top:0; 
right:0; left:0; text-align:center; position:relative; line-height:1.25em;}

#G {height:auto; margin-top:102px; padding:0; clear:both;}
#G img {display:none;}

nav {position: relative; top: 113px;}   
nav li a {width:100%; padding:0;}
nav ul li {width:100%; padding:0;}

nav ul li a {color: #949c50; font-size:1em; text-align:center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb1a6; display:block; padding:3%; width:94%; }

nav ul li#logo a {border-bottom: none; }
nav li:first-child {padding-top:40px; }

nav ul li a:hover { color: #FFF;background-color:#949c50;}
nav ul li#logo a:hover {background-color:transparent;}

a.mobile_menu {
display:block;
width:100%; height:38px;
background:#a54499
url(../links/mobile_link_menu.png)no-repeat 4px 4px;
position:absolute;
top:165px;
cursor:pointer;}

a.mobile_menu.selected {background-position: 4px -26px; }

li#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}}
```

Comment: Can you add placeholder images so I can see the sizes of the images involved?

Comment: I have added some placeholder images to give an idea of size: https://jsfiddle.net/td5n8ky9/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use padding-bottom in percent and height: 0

```
#Gray {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 31%;
    background-color: #bbb1a6;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly for when the browser is smaller - but problems still arise when the browser is larger - I have inputted the provided code into fiddle for you to see - https://jsfiddle.net/td5n8ky9/13/

Comment: I need the grey bar to stretch the width of the entire browser - this is the problem. Now the gray bar stays in proportion, but doesn't stretch the entire width of the browser.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much for all your assistance!